# Time to heat an object

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, thermal-conductivity

If I have a sphere of material (radius $= r$ and Temperature $= T_1$) in a hot environment $(T_h)$, how long will it take to heat the object to $T_2$, (where $T_1<T_2<T_h$) through to the centre?

I thought this would be fairly straightforward considering that heat transfer from inside a room through a window to outside is quite a commonly found example, but instead of going to outside, the heat is just going to the centre of the object.

However, I cannot find anything that references an equation to calculate this.

$Q=m \cdot c \cdot \Delta T$ and $t=Q/P$ is used often but it does not account for the shape or size of the object.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*from inside a room through a window to outside is quite a commonly found example*" The calculation for this is a common example? Or just numbers which could be obtained by experimentation? Because the calculation and others like it are NOT common. The issue with heating problems, and the equations you listed is not that they do not account for shape or size. It's that they do not account for the rates of heat transfer and the temperature gradient affecting each other. You need the heat equation which is a partial differential equation and that in itself takes advanced methods to solve.

Comment: My response would be that, it must be a fairly straightforward model because it is used every day to calculate cooking times for food. The products of these equations are literally everywhere, yet how to find the answer is not. I have found one source that suggests the answer is: t = (ρVC/hA).ln((T1-Th)/(T2-Th)) from "Fundamentals of Heat and Mass Transfer", but I am not too sure about this equation.

Comment: Are you just interested in the final result? If so, you can just blindly use the results here: https://www.sfu.ca/~mbahrami/ENSC%20388/Notes/Transient%20Heat%20Conduction.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Kyle's answer derives the transient temperature when the [Biot number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot_number) is small enough that the entire object is at a uniform temperature.

Somewhat more generally, for a [spherical geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula), the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation) is

$$\nabla^2T(r,t)=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial r}\right)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\partial T(r,t)}{\partial t},$$

where $r$ is the radial distance from the center and $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity of the sphere material (which is temperature-dependent in the general case). This would be solved numerically subject to the initial and boundary conditions.

Moving in the opposite direction of *less* sophistication, thermal diffusion times $t$ tend to scale with $L^2/\alpha$, where $L$ is a characteristic length. Thus, we can approximate $t$ as $t\sim R^2/\alpha$, where $R$ is the sphere radius. This broadly matches the $\sim\!\exp(-\text{Fo})$ term found in some of the comments to this thread, as the Fourier number $\text{Fo}\equiv\frac{\alpha t}{L^2}$. The scaling argument says that diffusion has progressed a fair amount toward steady state after one or several exponential time constants.

Comment: Thank you, and forgive my ignorance about thermodynamics since I am a Civil Engineer and not Mechanical or a Physicist. How might a solution to this look for some hypothetical boundary conditions?

Comment: Not at all! The relative temperature difference $\theta$ between the center of the sphere and the surroundings asymptotically approaches zero as an infinite sum of $\exp(-\zeta_i^2\text{Fo})$ terms, where $\zeta_i$ represents the positive roots of the transcendental equation $1-\zeta_i\cot\zeta_i=\text{Bi}$ and where $\text{Fo}$ and $\text{Bi}$ are the Fourier and Biot numbers, respectively. This is discussed in heat transfer textbooks and handbooks (e.g., Incropera & DeWitt, section 5.6 of the 7th edition).

Comment: The equation can also be solved analytically when assumptions to use separation of variables are applied. @EJones Heat transfer and thermodynamics are two complementary branches in studies of energy, not the same thing. The former is how heat (energy) is transported, the latter is how heat manifests itself as one form of energy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Mathematical_formulation_of_Newton%27s_law),
$$ \frac{\mathrm dQ}{\mathrm dt}=hA\left(T\left(t\right)-T_\text{h}\right), $$
where $A$ is the surface area and $h$ the heat transfer coefficient, along with the definition of the heat capacity, $\mathrm dQ=mC\mathrm dT$, to write,
$$ \frac{\mathrm dT}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{hA}{mC}\left(T\left(t\right)-T_\text{h}\right) =\frac{1}{\tau}\left(T\left(t\right)-T_\text{h}\right). $$
This has a solution of,
$$ T\left(t\right)=T_\text{h}+\left(T_1-T_\text{h}\right)\mathrm{e}^{-t/\tau} $$
which can be inverted to find the time to reach a temperature $T$,
$$ t\left(T\right)=-\frac{mC}{hA}\log\left(\frac{T-T_\text{h}}{T_1-T_\text{h}}\right) $$
Note that $m=\rho V$, so then the factor in front scales with length ($V/A\sim r$), so reaching $T_2<T_\text{h}$ will take longer for larger objects.

Comment: is h something that must be found experimentally?

Comment: You might note that this approach only applies if we assume the entire object heats or cools uniformly. The result is the called lumped analysis. The approach is not as straight forward when the object does not heat or cool uniformly. We will be directed to use a Heisler chart.

Comment: I assume that log is the natural log?

Comment: @EJones Yes. See, for instance, [this page](https://web1.eng.famu.fsu.edu/~alvi/EML4304L/webpage/experiment_8.htm)

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer That is a good point.

Comment: @electronpusher log is always natural log. If you want a different base, write a subscript.

Comment: Just to comment (again) ... log may always mean nature log *to physicists* (and to some programming software). By counter example, when chemists write pH = -log(H$^+$), they mean base 10 always. I therefore also recommend changing log to ln for improved clarity to a general audience.

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer Hard pass. See [this Math.Se post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90594/). I would also posit that one should be able to discern which log is intended based on context clues (i.e., you've got an exp in one line and a log in the next, it is a.s. not $\log_2$).

Comment: My reading in your referral says that ln is unambiguously natural log while log is sometimes log$_e$ (e.g. ln) or log$_{10}$ or log$_2$. What am I missing in reading your comment that log is *always* natural log when this comment appears to be countered by your more recent reference?

Comment: @JeffreyJWeimer You missed the very first comment on the top answer that states *Beware that log does not unambiguously mean the base-10 logarithm, but rather "the logarithm that we usually use".* Ergo: just use context clues.